# Replace |. with |0. in Unix Sun OS

Tags: shell, unix

I want to replace |. with |0. in my file. Tried below command but its not working since both are        special characters.

```
sed 's/\./0/\./g' PVC_.txt >> vc.txt

sed 's/\./0./g' CRP.txt >> cre1.txt
```

Please let me in replacing |. with |0.

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` in the replacement. I would think that second one should have worked. Are you sure it didn't? (Also neither of those limits the change to the `|.` pair and will make that change to all `.` in the file. To limit it `s/\|\./0&/g` should work (replace `&` with `|.` if your sed doesn't do `&` but I don't think that's a portability issue).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed 's/|\./|0./g' CRP.txt >> cre1.txt
```

Pipe is not considered special character in default `sed` mode.